# Filtering by file type in Microsoft Graph Shared With Me API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using this to get all files shared with me

`GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe`

I'm trying to filter for just pptx files shared with me using this but I get back "Only createdDateTime is supported for filtering".
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?$filter=endsWith(name,'.pptx')`

Is there another way to do this filtering?

Thanks!

Comment: Even i got the same info back. Sounds like thats the only property it supports at this point.

Comment: Being said that if you want Microsoft to implement the feature, do file a Microsoft Uservoice - so that they can consider it. Here's the closest uservoice that i can think off - https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35016886-add-support-for-descending-sort-order-to-onedrive